# OnSubmit JavaScript only working once for false entries, not repeating return to form, but submitting second time false values entered?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am new to programming and could do with some help can not find any clue, answer to this problem. Have checked JavaScript is ticked in Firefox 5.0.

Set up is I have a HTML page with one JavaScript check function at present for test development. It is linked to a servlet in Tomcat.

Problem is when I enter wrong the first time, get alert message and it returns to the HTML original page.

However if I click on entry field and enter wrong again.  It submits the form, does not give an alert or return to the original form?

Has any one got a solution or is this how validation should work.

Code is:

```
<HTML><head><title>Creation of POs</title>
<H1>Purchase Order</h1>
<script type="text/javaScript">
function check() {
check = document.forms[0].SLine1.value;
if(check=="wrong"){
alert("enter correct info");
return false;
} else {
return true; }
}
</script></head><body bgcolour="yellow">
<form method="GET" action="Distest_session30a_vs1" onSubmit="return 
check()">
various inputboxes and messages
<table>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="SLine1"></td></tr>
various other lines of inputs boxes
</table>
<Input type="submit" value="Send now">
</form></body></html>
```

Comment: It should be helpful to view the html code of the form

Comment: Script along with html code for form will be useful to know the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the form to be submitted, on the form, you can use `onsubmit="javascript:your_validation_function()"`. The form will only be submitted if the `your_validation_function()` returns true.

**EDIT**_ Looking at your HTML and js code together, I have found your problem. This js code should work:

```
function check(){ 
  var check = document.forms[0].SLine1.value; 
  if(check=="wrong"){ 
    alert("enter correct info"); 
    return false; 
  } 
  else{ 
    return true; 
  } 
}
```

Your problem was that you forgot to correctly declare the `check` var inside the function. If you are going to use variables, you need to use **var**.

Comment: Thanks tried changing this from onSubmit="return check()" to onSubmit="javascript:check()"  (check() is my validation fuction. )  This did not work unforetunately after enter wrong the value that should have returned false in my check() function, the form was submitted, it not give me the alert as before on the first time I entered wrong and clicked on submit button.  Which it was not repeating the second time I entered wrong on form, submitted it, instead of returning form as I would expect since function should have returned false again.

Comment: Post the html and the js code, it will be very helpful for us to try to figure out what's going on...

Comment: <HTML><head><title>Creation of POs</title>
<H1>Purchase Order</h1>
<script type="text/javaScript">
function check() {
check = document.forms[0].SLine1.value;
if(check=="wrong"){
alert("enter correct info");
return false;
} else {
return true; }
}
</script></head><body bgcolour="yellow">
<form method="GET" action="Distest_session30a_vs1" onSubmit="return 
check()">
various inputboxes and messages
<table>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="SLine1"></td></tr>
various other lines of inputs boxes
</table>
<Input type="submit" value="Send now">
</form></body></html>

Comment: Sorry pressed enter by mistake.  Code is:  <HTML><head><title>Creation of POs</title>
<H1>Purchase Order</h1>
<script type="text/javaScript">
function check() {
check = document.forms[0].SLine1.value; -been advised might be this form[1] 2nd time. But how to solve?
if(check=="wrong"){
alert("enter correct info");
return false;
} else {
return true; }
}
</script></head><body bgcolour="yellow">
<form method="GET" action="Distest_session30a_vs1" onSubmit="return 
check()">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="SLine1"></td></tr>
</table>
<Input type="submit" value="Send now">
</form> etc.

Comment: Resolved.  Issue was need to make variable non global.  check=document.forms[0].SLine1.value apparently made it global.  Need to change to var check=document.forms[0].SLine1.value.  It was not to do with forms[0] changing on the second time a wrong was entered.  Thanks for all the help

Comment: Isn't that what Victor said? >.< If you got your answer, Beverley, mark the answer "accepted" please.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do ?.

```
          <script type="text/javascript">

              function check() {
                                    check = document.forms[0].SLine1.value;
                                    if(check=="wrong")
                                     { 
                                       alert("enter correct info"); 
                                        return false;
                                     } 
                                     else if("right")
                                     {
                                       alert("right");
                                       return true; 
                                     }

                                } 
           </script>

          <form onsubmit="check()">
            <input type="text" id="SLine1">
                <input  type="submit">
         </form>
```

Comment: I have tried you suggestion of changing input type="text" name="SLine1"> to <input type="text" id="SLine1">  unforetunately this did not work , still got it giving me alert returning to orginal form first time, but on entering wrong again it sumbiting the form.

Comment: I have also tried your full solution both with out the OnSubmit = "return check ()" and <form onsubmit="check()">.  With both it did the same, displayed alert, returned to orginal page and then on second time wrong was enter, submitted form.  With just form onsubmit="check", it did not raise alert the first time, just submitted the form, and returned a different page from server as per my servlet.  Want to find a robust way of not submiting the form until a correct value is entered.

Comment: Only "wrong" and "right" will be the values entered from the input box ? If that it is the case then you can keep else if block for "right" value or some other value.

Comment: Actually this was just a development test, I want to set up lots of different check, in this field it would be, that text entered and meets a regular expression, but first need to get a function that determining a false value always returns you back to entry field until function returns a true?

Comment: Using the above code the same problem persists for you ? .I think the validations are working properly there.